# Extract equation from model with co-efficient

Tags: python, r, regression

I have a simple question, I run a linear model using below

```
model1 <- lm(output ~. , data=df)
```

I get some output, I want to extract linear equation directly instead of seeing output in raw form

I know broom package what I do best is

```
   library(broom)
    tidy(mod1)
```

I want output in form

```
output=1.1*var1 + 1.2*var2+....
```

Comment: Why is this tagged python? And what type of output are you trying to get, a single string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at equatiomatic package (https://github.com/datalorax/equatiomatic)

Below code should solve your problem, I am using iris as an example

```
remotes::install_github("datalorax/equatiomatic")
library(equatiomatic)
mod1 <- lm(Petal.Width~.-Species, data= iris)
extract_eq(mod1, use_coefs = TRUE, wrap=TRUE,fix_signs = FALSE,ital_vars = TRUE,terms_per_line = 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I just added load line

Comment: This outputs Latex, so it's only useful in the context of converting output to a PDF, such as in rmarkdown output. The OP hasn't specified that that's what they're doing

Comment: Agree, to some extent. Is there a better way to this ? Would be happy to learn :)